# Array in MongoDB

Tags: c#-4.0, mongodb

How to get the single array element document with their objecID? For example the collection has an array but the array has own objectid and other properties.

`Dc.Collection.FindOne(query);` cant get the particular array document if i passed the array element objectid.

Answer (score 1):

Does the array contain embedded documents, as in

```
{
    ObjectId : // some ID,
    ArrayField : [ 
        {
            ObjectId: // id,
            key: value
        },  
        {
            ObjectId: // id, 
            key: value2
        }
    ]
}
```

?  In that case, you would want to query using dot notation, for instance:

`findOne({"ArrayField.key" : value1 })`

would match this document.  Take a look at the fifth code example on this page:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+(Reaching+into+Objects)